# Jenkins Multiple Slave node configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Our requirement is to we have two slave nodes and one jenkins job. Based on a parameter we must be able to decide where the job has to be run on node1 or node 2. Is there any plugin available?

Answer (score 1):

i did by using build param. From add parameter add 'Node' then set the name of the parameter and other setting. you you have to setup Node[Build machine].  for your information.i added a picture. [image]